# Paw: Possible to copy/paste data from Hash/Dictionary source in target language?

Tags: ruby, paw-app

I'm using Paw to integrate with an API and it's a great tool, but the codebase I'm working in has lots of data in Ruby `Hash`es already that I would like to bring into Paw for testing. Moreover, I would like to be able to copy the data out of a Paw response for use in Ruby code rather than having to copy JSON and either store it as a String and parse it in my code or manually convert it to a native dictionary data structure. Is this possible?

Comment: What's so hard about `JSON.dump` and `JSON.load`? Ruby hash notation is not something Paw accepts, but JSON is. If you're really bent out of shape by this, why not [write an extension](https://paw.cloud/extensions/)?

Comment: I didn't say it was hard; I said it shouldn't be necessary. I don't want my test suite, for instance, having to repeatedly `JSON.load`. And I definitely don't want `JSON.load` in my production code and converting between the two is a pain in its current form.  I'll look at possibly creating a code generator extension, but that still doesn't help with bringing Hashes from Ruby into Paw for testing.

Comment: Why not dump out the results from Paw in to plain old `.json` files and put that in your application if necessary? Store data as data, code as code. Storing data as code makes for the sort of mess you're getting into where you need to convert it and so on.